# Creating a COM Port Redirector over the Network

Tags: windows, drivers

I'm trying to create a windows driver that allows a standard TCP/IP socket to be used like a COM Port.  I am aware of a number of existing products that do just this, but can find no reference material as to how it's actually done! I understand some of the concepts of windows drivers (bus/function/filter drivers, driver stacks, etc), and have tried reading a book on WDF, but I'm still not 100% sure on where I start if there is no actual backing hardware.  If anyone has any links/pointers that will help, it would be much appreciated.

Kazar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) project. They also offer an com2tcp driver. As it is open source you can go through the sources and get an idea of how it's done.

Actually this is not a driver, but an app, so it might be less helpful in your task to learn something about driver development, but anyway could be a good starter for some technical insight.

Comment: There is a driver as part of the code, so cheers, doesn't help there are no comments of any form, but ah well.

Comment: Yes, my answer is a bit confusing. I just meant, the com2tcp part is not a driver.